# Android what is the best way to auto-connect to ble device

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently trying to make an Android app that will have some interaction with a BLE device. That device doesn't have the Ibeacon protocol.

What I want to do is auto connect to that device every time it is in range even (and almost 99% of the time) when the app is not in foreground. The only thing I know is that it is a BLE device, I have access to it name and address (00:1E:C0:29:BD:F8).

It is crucial tha the app connect to it every time it come in range. Even if the phone is lock it must connect no matter what (except if the phone is shut down XD). But as soon as the phone has booted and that bluetooth is activated, I must be sure that my app will be able to connect to tha device if it come in range.

I wanted to know what is the best way to do so.

The only way I can think of is to start a service as sticky, that will scan every 15 seconds (or something similar) for the device it already has registered to auto-connect.

The downfall of that method I guess is that it will surely drain the battery, I'm not sure about that but doing a scan for 3 to 4 second every 15 second must use up a lot of battery.

What do you guys think of that ?
Does anybody know a better solution I could use ?

Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you come up with any best approach for this scenario?

Comment: @Darshna Desai Sorry, I don't remember what I did in the end to make it work, it's been 4 years that this project was completed

Comment: No problem, Thanks anyway.